# How to solve SecurityException: Permission Denial error on API 23 (Marshmallow)?

Tags: java, android

I have been getting this this weird Force Close of my app when someone on android 6.0 tries to upload a photo on my app while the app works compeletly fine on Android Kitkat, here is my logcat

```
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.ummahtalk.network, PID: 14882
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:53790 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.ummahtalk.network/com.ummahtalk.network.activities.posts.PublishActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=14882, uid=10166 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3743)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3786)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=14882, uid=10166 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:493)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:435)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ummahtalk.network.helpers.FilePath.getDataColumn(FilePath.java:117)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ummahtalk.network.helpers.FilePath.getPath(FilePath.java:82)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ummahtalk.network.activities.posts.PublishActivity.setImageUriValue(PublishActivity.java:468)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.ummahtalk.network.activities.posts.PublishActivity.onActivityResult(PublishActivity.java:238)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6456)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3739)
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3786) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap16(ActivityThread.java) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1412) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5466) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
03-29 18:36:33.627 14882-14882/com.ummahtalk.network E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please, reformat the log message. This looks like you have not asked for the permission to `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/images/media from pid=14882, uid=10166 requires **android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**, or grantUriPermission()

Comment: what am I missing here?

Comment: When you get an error log, you have to read the line stating the error, here `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo...`. If that doesn't help you, read the following line starting with `Caused by:`

Comment: Google "Android Runtime Permissions", c'mon, it's been more than half a year since Android 6 SDK came out a people are still baffled by this.

Comment: Beyond this, just from the stack trace, it would appear that you think that reading a `DATA` column is going to be useful. There is no requirement that any `Uri` have access to some `DATA` column, and even if one does, it may not result in some file path that you can use successfully. Please use `Uri` values properly: https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html

Answer (score 2):

Android-M ie, API 23 introduced [Runtime Permissions](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) for reducing security flaws in android device, where users can now directly manage app permissions at runtime.so if the user denies a particular permission of your application you have to obtain it by asking the permission dialog that you mentioned in your query.

So check before action ie, check you have permission to access the resource [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-check) and if your application doesn't have that particular permission you can request the permission [link](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request) and handle the the permissions request response like below.

> ```
> @Override
> public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
>         String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
>             // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
>             if (grantResults.length > 0
>                 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>                 
>                 // permission was granted, yay! Do the
>                 // contacts-related task you need to do.
>           
>                } else {
>
>                 // permission denied, boo! Disable the
>                 // functionality that depends on this permission.
>             }
>             return;
>         }
>
>         // other 'case' lines to check for other
>         // permissions this app might request
>     }
> }
> ```

So finally, It's a good practice to go through [behavior changes](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-runtime-permissions) if you are planning to work with new versions to avoid force closes :)

[Permissions Best Practices.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/best-practices.html)

You can download official sample app [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/RuntimePermissions/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your application doesnt have the right permission (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`).

The problem is that in Android 6 you must check permissions in runtime. You can find more info here:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Answer (score 1):

**You need to request permissions at RunTime**

Since API 23 you have to request permissions at Run Time, permissions from Manifest are not automatically granted.

More at: http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Keep in mind that sometimes you have to explain to user why does your application need these permissions.